# Finding min and max values of an array of arrays using D3.JS not plain Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I have an array of arrays looking like this:

```
series = [ [ { "x":2013-01-01, "y":100 }, { "x":2013-01-02, "y":300 } ...],
           [ { "x":2013-01-01, "y":1000 }, { "x":2013-01-02, "y":300 } ...],...
         ]
```

How do I get the min and max values of "x" and "y" using d3?

I know that for a single array like the following:

```
miniseries = [ { "x":2013-01-01, "y":100 }, { "x":2013-01-02, "y":300 } ...]
```

I would use for example the following sentence:

```
minX = d3.min(miniseries, function(d){return d.x});
```

But not sure how to deal with an array of arrays rather than the single array.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff : My question was a D3.JS question, I was not interested in a JavaScript answer. The question "How to find the max/min of a nested array in javascript? " is misleading because does not mention D3.JS at all (I agree is does mention D3 later in the details ). I think is should be reworded so users can understand from reading the question that is a D3.JS problem/solution not a JavaScript one

Comment: Feel free to suggest edits to the question. It is tagged with D3 though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var minX = d3.min(series, function (ms) {
    return d3.min(ms, function (d) {
        return d.y
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over the data-array and store the values in two arrays (one for each axis). Then you can get the min/max values of both axes as follows:

To find the min/max date (x-Axis):

```
// sample data
var dates = [ 
    new Date("2013-01-01"),
    new Date("2013-02-01"),
    new Date("2013-03-01")
];

var minDate = new Date(Math.min.apply(null, dates));
var maxDate = new Date(Math.max.apply(null, dates));
```

To find the min/max value (y-Axis):

```
// sample data
var valuesAxisY = [100, 300, 400, 50];

var min = Math.min.apply(null, valuesAxisY),
var max = Math.max.apply(null, valuesAxisY);
```

Comment: I am getting the series as a result of a JSON call with other key and values that I did not described in my example because is not related to my question. So I rather use the series array as is. More importantly, I am learning D3.JS and want to know how to do it using d3.js rather than plain JavaScript.